# I am getting information from an API but i am not able to use it

Tags: php, json, node.js, api

I want to start a node js application through my PHP file. 
After that, I want to save the outcome in a variable like $result

The data looks like that:

```
[{ id: 'ID', displayName: 'DisplayedName' },
{ id: 'ID', displayName: 'DisplayedName' },
 ...]
```

and I don't know how to use this.

My Questions:

1. Is there a way to convert this into a JSON file, if so how?
2. Is there a way to use the data(extract information out of it), if so how?

## Edit: added the function

this is one of the functions

```
static get Sth1() { return "sth1" }
static get Sth2() { return "sth2" }
static get Sth3() { return "sth3" }    

getMeSth(platform,type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!(platform == "pc" || platform == "ps4" || platform == "xb1")) {
            reject("Please precise a good platform: ps4/xb1/pc")
        }

        if(!(type == this.constructor.Sth1 || type == this.constructor.Sth2 || type == this.constructor.Sth3)) {
            reject("Please precise a good type test.Sth1/test.Sth2/test.Sth3")
        }

        request({
            url: EndPoint.leaderBoardScore(platform,type),
            headers: {
                Authorization: "author " + this.access_token
            },
            method: "POST",
            json: true
        }).then(leaderboard => {
            leaderboard = leaderboard.entries

            leaderboard.forEach(i => {
                i.accountId = i.accountId.replace(/-/g,'')
            })

            request({
                url: EndPoint.displayNameFromIds(leaderboard.map(i => i.accountId)),
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "author " + this.access_token
                },
                method: "GET",
                json: true
            }).then(displayNames => {
                leaderboard.forEach(i => {
                    i.displayName = displayNames.find(ii => ii.id === i.accountId).displayName
                })

                resolve(JSON.stringify(leaderboard))
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(err)
            })

        })
        .catch(err => {
            reject(err)
        })
    })
}
```

## Edit: added the outcome

all right now that I built in JSON.stringify() in to the application i get this data

```
[{"accountId":"ID1","value":913,"rank":1,"displayName":"Name1"},{"accountId":"ID2","value":892,"rank":2,"displayName":"Name2"},{"accountId":"ID3","value":868,"rank":3,"displayName":"Name3"},...]
```

How can i extract the important information like Value/Rank/DisplayName???

Comment: See `json_decode()` in of all the odd and unusual places. **The PHP Manual**

Comment: No thats not valid JSON @RiggsFolly the keys and string values needs to be double qoutes.

Comment: @RaymondNijland YUP Good point, well made

Comment: How do you build `$result` i.e. the non JSON data

Comment: i am not building it thats what i get from the api

Comment: i inserted one of the functions i use to get the data

Comment: The Node application should use `JSON.stringify()` when it prints the data. Then PHP can use `json_docode()` to parse it.

Comment: PHP can use `shell_exec()` to execute the Node application and read the output that it prints.

Comment: This is also a promise anti-pattern.  There's no need to wrap one promise in another.  Just return the promise from `request()`.

Comment: @Barmar I <3 you so much thx I am now getting data thats formatted in JSON, but now i have another problem. i can start my node js application through my php file but i can not close it. Any Idea?

Comment: https://eval.in/996567 am i thinkin wrong here???

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

I just added `{"leaderboard":` to the biggining and `}` to the end.
Now it is a JSON Object with an array where many other objects are inside.

```
$output = "{\"leaderboard\"" . ":" . exec('node /path/to/node/js/file/doSth.js &') . "}";
```

now my `$output` is

```
{"leaderboard":[{"accountId":"ID1","value":913,"rank":1,"displayName":"Name1"},{"accountId":"ID2","value":892,"rank":2,"displayName":"Name2"},{"accountId":"ID3","value":868,"rank":3,"displayName":"Name3"},...]}
```

and i can extract my infos with

```
$DName = json_decode($output, true);
echo $DName['leaderboard'][0]['displayName'];
```

I hope this helps.